# How to iterate over an array from a model

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an API which returns a reponse like this:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "20",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/20"
    },

    {
      "id": "21",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/20"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am mapping the response to a C# model like this:

```
namespace TestApp.Models
{
  public class TestSuiteModel 
  {
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
  }

  public class Value
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I initialize the model in my `index.razor` page as:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await this.GetTestSuites();
}


TestSuiteModel TestSuitesResult;
protected async Task GetTestSuites()
{
  // url = ... 
  TestSuitesResult = await TestSuiteService.GetTestSuites(url);
  await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

`TestSuitesResult` works fine as of this step, in that I can do a foreach loop and see the json reponse displayed on my blazor page.

The only issue I have is when I use the library: https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop

The library says to use the drag and drop service as:

```
<Dropzone Items="MyItems">
  <div>@context.MyProperty</div>
</Dropzone>
```

`MyItems` is a sample array and `MyProperty` is an array key.

But when I use it like this, it doesn't work:

```
<Dropzone Items="TestSuitesResult">
  <div>@context.value</div>
</Dropzone>
```

I get an error saying TestSuitesResult isn't valid. I don't know how else to pass the array into the component

Comment: What is the type of *TestSuitesResult*? It doesn't look like it's a collection.

Comment: As @AleksaMajkic mentioned, please post your: TestSuiteModel

Comment: @AleksaMajkic Sorry, `TestSuiteModel` is actually included in the example, I corrected the the mistake now

Comment: @Waragi Updated now, please take another look. The model I posted it is `TestSuiteModel` I used another name that I no longer use in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Dropzone component is trying to use the entire *TestSuitesResult* object as an array of items, but it expects an array of values. You should assign the value property of the *TestSuitesResult* object to the *Items* property of the Dropzone component instead:

```
<Dropzone Items="TestSuitesResult.value">
<div>@context.id</div>
</Dropzone>
```

Also, it's possible that the *TestSuitesResult* object isn't yet populated when the Dropzone component is rendered. To solve this issue, you can consider using a loading indicator to only render the Dropzone component after the TestSuitesResult object has been populated.

```
@if (TestSuitesResult != null)
{
 <Dropzone Items="TestSuitesResult.value">
 <div>@context.value</div>
 </Dropzone>
}
else
{
  // ... loading
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the **Dropzone** component is rendered, it's possible the **TestSuitesResult** object isn't yet populated. You also aren't targeting the List object. Try the implementation below:

```
@if(TestSuitesResult != null)
    {
      <Dropzone Items="TestSuitesResult.value">
          <div>@context.url </div>
      </Dropzone>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<Value> TestSuitesResult;
protected async Task GetTestSuites()
{
  // url = ... 
  var model = await TestSuiteService.GetTestSuites(url);
  TestSuitesResult = model.value;

  await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dropzone component actually expects you to provide a property which implements `IList<T>`

You can see this when pressing F12 within Visual Studio on the parameters name. Or within the code on Github.

```
public IList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
```

So all you'll need to do is to provide your Values to the component.

```
@if (TestSuitesResult != null)
{
    <Dropzone Items="TestSuitesResult.value">
        <div>@context.id</div> @* access properties from Value class here *@
    </Dropzone>
}
```